# Exception creating type for an adapter in a Sharepoint website?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2007, adapter, cssadapter

I have a website in Sharepoint 2007. I use control adapters, specifically an adapter for the menu and the login control. These two adapters resides in a signed assembly that it is deployed to the bin folder of the website.
The browser

```
<browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
             adapterType="NameofEnterprise.SecondName.Adapters.MenuAdapter" />
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login"
         adapterType="NameofEnterprise.SecondName.Adapters.LoginAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
```

From time to time I get the following exception, just from time to time, let's say once or twice a day:

```
Unable to create type 'NameofEnterprise.SecondName.Adapters.MenuAdapter'.
```

Things to take in mind: this happens in the machine I develop, I don't know if there are temporary files that can get the framework crazy. Second, I don't know if the framework perhaps is looking for the class of the Adapter in another assembly, as I have some assemblies that have the same namespaces as this one, that is to say: NameofEnterprise.SecondName.BusinessLayer,NameofEnterprise.SecondName.DataLayer....

Plz could you tell me what can be the problem? Can I be more specific to tell the framework the name of the assembly (in the browser you only write the name of the class and namespace)?

**SOLUTION**

Finally i have used the 2 advices you have given me. I think that with the first thing is enough, that is to say:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="*<Your assembly name here>*"/>
    </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

But i have included two the assembly and public token in the browser:

```
<browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
             adapterType="NameofEnterprise.SecondName.Adapters.MenuAdapter", YourAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YourPublicKeyToken"/>
    </controlAdapters>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify your web.config, adding your assembly to the list of assemblies:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="*<Your assembly name here>*"/>
    </assemblies>
    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

Add the assembly that contains your controls, and the error should disappear.  For future reference, Temp internet files has almost *nothing* to do with Asp.net errors.  Though you can clear them if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I didn't refer to temp internet files, i referred to Framework temporary files, located in: \WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v...\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Answer (score 1):

It's also useful to use the full qualified name when you add the reference to your assembly:

```
<browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
             adapterType="NameofEnterprise.SecondName.Adapters.MenuAdapter", YourAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YourPublicKeyToken"/>
    </controlAdapters>
```